# jQuery How to differentiate which "<select id=" value/ID was changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-select, onchange

My main question is, how do I tell apart which drop down box was changed? 
Essentially I have this HTML code of dropdown boxes/ComboBoxes, which is populated by a JSON File in JS.

```
            <select id="filterCountry">
              <option value="0">All Countries</option>
            </select>
            <select id="filterBrowser">
              <option value="0">All Browsers</option>
            </select>
            <select id="filterOS">
              <option value="0">All Operating System</option>
            </select>
```

My jQuery code is now something along the lines of this.

```
$("#filterBrowser, #filterOS, #filterCountry").change(function(e){
    alert("Something has been changed "  + this.value);

    // Ugly pseudocode but something along the lines of...
    if(("#filterBrowser").change) {
        console.log("the browser drop down was changed");
    } else if (("#filterOS").change) {
        console.log("The OS drop down changed");
    } else if(("#filterCountry").change) {
        console.log("The country drop down was changed")
    }
});
```

Comment: You’re looking for: `this.id`

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica - technically, it's `this` - as it should be the select element that was changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the id of the element which threw the event.  For example:

```
if(this.id === 'filterBrowser') {
  //...
}
```